# Typescript - Infer strongly-typed recursive index type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Starting with an **Animal** interface, and a map of animals in my farm:

```
export interface Animal {
   type: string;
   edible: boolean;
}
export interface Farmland{
   [key: string]: Animal;
}
```

All works good. Here's my farm -

```
const farm: Farmland = {

  bob: { type: 'sheep', edible: true },
  daisy: { type: 'cow', edible: true }

}
```

Now my farn might have some smaller parts in it, and I want a new type which will contain either the animals or these parts:

```
export interface FarmlandOrAnimalMap {
  [key: string]: Animal | Farmland;
}

const bigField: FarmlandOrAnimalMap = {

  bob: { type: 'sheep', edible: true },
  daisy: { type: 'cow', edible: true },

  pasture: {
    jack: { type: 'dog', edible: false }
  },
  pond: {
    donald: { type: 'duck', edible: true }
  },
  farmhouse: {
    hernietta: { type: 'monkey', edible: false }
  }
};
```

That seems to work too - I can happily reference `{{bigField.pond.donald.edible}}` (using e.g. angular) and all other expected object properties in my markup. Here's what I **can't** do though -

```
export class AnimalOven{

  constructor() {

    const donald = bigField.pond.donald;

  }
}
```

The error is `Property 'donald' does not exist on type 'Animal | Farmland'.  Property 'donald' does not exist on type 'Animal'` . (This error will also be thrown by an angular compiler when I build the application.)

Typescript evidently knows `bigField.pond` ***might*** be Farmland (with its string index) ***or*** an Animal so I'm not sure why it cannot infer the correct type here. In short:

**Is there a way for Typescript to correctly infer type when using a type union of *strong-type* and {[key:index]: *strong-type*} ?**

(Obviously there might be better ways of creating my farm and animals, use of keys, appropriate use of arrays; but the question here really relates to *Typescript inference of map types*)

Thanks.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: what you're doing here is that you're mixing up the types: are your keys going to be Animals, or "areas" in the farm? Perhaps you should instead store the areas as properties of the animals. To generate a list of animals from an area in the farmland you can then use `.filter()` to retrieve them. Of course, you can always do it the dirty way, by telling TypeScript that you "know" what a key is, i.e. `const donald = (bigField.pond as Record<string, Animal>).donald;`, but I see this as a code smell.

Comment: Thanks, yeah the whole farm thing is a way to try to describe the problem that, in essence, typescript cannot seem to work with a union of *strong-type* and {[key:index]: *strong-type*} - that's what I'm trying to get to the bottom of. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Have you considered using an atomized data structure instead? Something like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEMqoDZaIAmAglMFnAN4BQc9cACiQMoAqAqgEoCiANHQaMA8gDkAIgIaYSXALIAJYRxb8aAXxo1QkWHACWiGMCgAzLAGNgcEon2oseaoPqIsqYAC44AZxhRDAHMAbhc4GABPMC9ffyDQ6WAifQAjPBiUiAh0wgSGHApvbFwCYjIKOAAfOBQ8PFDNGgsIRD84QntHH29bTrwAbQBdOABeOH7aaTcPbwByTJTZqQZI6LmfAAtgYDAlsKTU9O9-ZGBl+gKsb1q8AXU+Zyn3GNmiFsciPelVl6JkCwA1l8GAc0jETmcwpcijh8IRSOQsAA6EQSO6DULacDQeAWAg+Hw2OwOPDCABuSEmcGarROFhg0AAFABKR4MGltN5uPBEUbtYldJGmQxERmMjok1kjAB8-L6SOm1hGyrgr3ePNmzLymnUQA

Answer (score 0):

By declaring it to be a `FarmlandOrAnimalMap` you tell the compiler that the content of the variable is more generic than what it actually is here.

If you take away the type annotation of `bigField`, this will work as the type of the entire object tree is derived.

For any variable of type `FarmlandOrAnimalMap` the compiler can never infer whether a property is an `Animal` or `Farmland` unless you introduce additional checks.